# What is sonarqube status PENDING, IN_PROGRESS?

Tags: sonarqube

I ran sonarqube by using Jenkins with maven build.
When it build success, but I can not see report on sonarqube web page.
Like this,,, build succeeded

```
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18:21 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-02-15T10:44:14+09:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving
```

When I went to url in log 
- INFO: More about the report processing at http://127.0.0.1:9000/sonarqube/api/ce/task?id=AVo_WHJYU5rNTJ7ZmiZq

```
{"task":{"id":"AVo_WHJYU5rNTJ7ZmiZq","type":"REPORT","componentId":"AVk906UDu6xeCo3BQ_gU","componentKey":"online","componentName":"AMIS3-Online","componentQualifier":"TRK","status":"PENDING","submittedAt":"2017-02-15T10:17:46+0900","submitterLogin":"admin","logs":false}}
```

What is the status Pending?.. 
Build succeeded, but Why status is pending??
And I can not see Report in sonarqube webpage..

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 8):

Analysis happens in two steps:

1. A SonarQube Scanner runs on your code, compiles an analysis report, and submits it to the server
2. The analysis report is processed on the server side and the project updated in the database

Step #1 happens synchronously. Step #2 happens asynchronously.

When an analysis/report is in `PENDING` state on the server side, it means that it is queued and waiting to be processed.

When an analysis/report moves to `IN_PROGRESS`, it means it has reached the head of the queue, been popped off, and is being integrated, server side. This integration doesn't happen instantly; there are aggregated metrics to compute and the database to update. Depending on the size of the project and the resources available to the server this could happen very quickly or take a few minutes.

To see what's going on in the processing queue, take a look at **Administration > Projects > Background Tasks**

Comment: Thanks your answer..

I think Step #1 finished. because I can not see build error logs...

And It passed about 4 hours after build finished.
But the status is still PENDING.
My project is big size. It's all about 572MB,, and 98,166 files.. Because of that, the status is not change??

I'm curious.. How long does it takes to finish? I think stauts will not be change in my case..

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could see reports of our project in the webpage.
As you say, I could see start, end time in a Background Tasks page.
started time was (+2d)12:26:49. It means that Uploading reports to server starts 2 days after, when it finished analyze?